# How to disable URLs from PageSpeed Service on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, pagespeed

Some URLs should not be touched by PageSpeed Service. According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#pagespeed I just need to add those URLs to a `url_blacklist` field in my `app.yaml`. However, it doesn't appear to be working.

Here's what I have:

```
pagespeed:
  enabled_rewriters:
    - InlineImages
    - CollapseWhitespace
    - RemoveComments
    - InlineJs
  url_blacklist:
    - http://*/code/out/*
    - https://*/code/out/*
```

This URL is still being handled by PageSpeed Service:

http://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/code/out/hello_world.html

What am I doing wrong? How can I exclude my URL in a generic fashion? (If possible, I want to use * wildcards to avoid having to specify every URL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked around this issue with the following configuration:

```
pagespeed:
  enabled_rewriters:
    - InlineImages
    - CollapseWhitespace
    - RemoveComments
    - InlineJs
  url_blacklist:
    - http://www.dartlang.org/*/code/out/*
    - https://www.dartlang.org/*/code/out/*
```

Which is interesting, because the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#pagespeed) imply I can do `http://*/*.svg`